# Bon appetit : printing a string in main() from a int return type function

Tags: c++

Problem is ..i have to print "Bon appetit" in `int main()` from a function having `int` return type ..here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum -= ar[k];

    if(sum/2 == b)
        cout<< "Bon Appetit"<<endl;
    else
        return b-(sum/2);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> ar(n);
    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
       cin >> ar[ar_i];
    }
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    int result = bonAppetit(n, k, b, ar);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if i use `cout<<"Bon appetit"` ..in the output ,it is shown as `Bon appetit0` due to `return b-(sum/2)` .
another problem is my ide wont let me write `return b/(sum)/2` in the `else` part,otherwise a warning is generated which is being treated as a error and the code wont simply compile :
     `control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror = return type]`

so, in short ""HOW DO I RETURN A STRING TO MAIN() FROM A INT TYPE FUNCTION" ?
  Please dont suggest to not to use a function and write the code firectly in main().

link to problem ==> https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bon-appetit/problem

Comment: Are you really trying to return "the string to main" or you just want to display the string from the function?

Comment: display will also work....i just have to print it to main.....it doesnt matter whether you use "return" or display it directly..

Comment: An unrelated note: you should pass vector to the function by `const &` to avoid vector copying which might be costly on large inputs.

Comment: @Mikhail i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
        sum += i;

    sum -= ar[k];

    if(sum/2 == b)
        return -1;
    else
        return b-(sum/2);
}
```

and in main:

```
if (result != -1) std::cout << result << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Bon Appetit" << std::endl;
```

Please, do not use `using namespace std`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/7943474) why

Comment: The code in main will not compile because `result` and `"Bon appetit"` have different types and ternary operator does not support it.

Comment: you are right @Mikhail ..if u prefre .have a look at problem in the link ....it may clear my question better

Answer (score 1):

you can return two value from one function by using byRef Arguments. this is a simple sample:

```
char* isDividableOn(int num, int divider ,int & remain){

   if ( num % divider == 0){
        remain = 0;
        return "number is dividable";
   }
   else {
        remain = num % divider;
        return "number is not dividable";
   }
}

int main (){
    int num = 11;
    int divider = 3;
    int res = -1;
    cout << isDividableOn(num , divider, res);
    /// in this point  value of res now is set to 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every flow of your fonction must return a `int`. So just display your text and then return.

```
int bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum -= ar[k];

    if(sum/2 == b)
        cout<< "Bon Appetit"<<endl;

    return b-(sum/2);
}
```

If you really need to "return" the string to main, it means your function returns both `int` and a ̀`string`. In C++, a function has only one return type. Then, you have several options to have your function provide two outputes (`int` and `string`). Here are two simple options:

Return a `pair` (`int` and `string`):

```
pair<int,string> bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum -= ar[k];

    return make_pair( b-(sum/2), ((sum/2 == b) ? "Bon Appetit" : "") );
}
```

Then your main will do:

```
pair<int,string> result = bonAppetit(n, k, b, ar);
if ( !result.second.empty() )
    cout << result.second << endl;
cout << result.first << endl;
```

Or have a `string` be passed as reference to the function (if not a `const` reference, it will let your function modify it):

```
int bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar, string& message) 
{
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum -= ar[k];

    if (sum/2 == b)
        message = "Bon Appetit";

    return b-(sum/2);
}
```

Then your main will do:

```
string text;
int result = bonAppetit(n, k, b, ar, text);
if ( !text.empty() )
    cout << text << endl;
cout << result.first << endl;
```

Comment: i doubt if ternary operator supports two different return types

Answer (score 0):

it worked :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string bonAppetit(int n, int k, int b, vector <int> ar) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = 0; 
    for(auto i : ar )
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum -= ar[k];

    if(sum/2 == b)
        return "Bon Appetit";

       string str = to_string(b-(sum/2));
   return str;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> ar(n);
    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
       cin >> ar[ar_i];
    }
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    string result = bonAppetit(n, k, b, ar);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next time, try to ask the question correctly then other people than you may answer it....

Comment: @jpo38 I added a link to the original problem.... And this solution was suggested by someone in comment on top